# How to convert interface{} to string?

Tags: go

I'm using [docopt](http://docopt.org/) to parse command-line arguments. This works, and it results in a map, such as

```
map[<host>:www.google.de <port>:80 --help:false --version:false]
```

Now I would like to concatenate the `host` and the `port` value to a string with a colon in-between the two values. Basically, something such as:

```
host := arguments["<host>"] + ":" + arguments["<port>"]
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as I get the error message:

> invalid operation: arguments[""] + ":" (mismatched types interface {} and string)

So obviously I need to convert the value that I get from the map (which is just `interface{}`, so it can be anything) to a string. Now my question is, how do I do that?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

Comment: `fmt.Sprint(data)` // where data is interface{}

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You need to add [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) `.(string)`. It is necessary because the map is of type `map[string]interface{}`:

```
host := arguments["<host>"].(string) + ":" + arguments["<port>"].(string)
```

Latest version of Docopt returns [Opts](https://godoc.org/github.com/docopt/docopt-go#Opts) object that has methods for conversion:

```
host, err := arguments.String("<host>")
port, err := arguments.String("<port>")
host_port := host + ":" + port
```

Comment: Would like to add that this is called Type Assertion - https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions. I once had trouble figuring out this exact terminology.

Comment: It will cause a panic if arguments["<host>"] is nil

Answer (score 114):

You don't need to use a type assertion, instead just use the `%v` format specifier with `Sprintf`:

```
hostAndPort := fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v", arguments["<host>"], arguments["<port>"])
```

Comment: This was the only thing I could get to work for me when trying to type cast interface{}'s with as strings.

Comment: For me, this didn't work. This ended up printing the byte ASCII charts instead of the string, like 201 become "[50,48,49]", so I ended up using fmt.Sprintf("%s", theThing) instead...

Answer (score 27):

To expand on what Peter said:
Since you are looking to go from interface{} to string, type assertion will lead to headaches since you need to account for multiple incoming types.  You'll have to assert each type possible and verify it is that type before using it.

Using fmt.Sprintf (https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) automatically handles the interface conversion.  Since you know your desired output type is always a string, Sprintf will handle whatever type is behind the interface without a bunch of extra code on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `text/template`:

```
package main

import (
   "text/template"
   "strings"
)

func format(s string, v interface{}) string {
   t, b := new(template.Template), new(strings.Builder)
   template.Must(t.Parse(s)).Execute(b, v)
   return b.String()
}

func main() {
   m := map[string]interface{}{"<host>": "www.google.de", "<port>": "80"}
   s := format(`{{index . "<host>"}}:{{index . "<port>"}}`, m)
   println(s == "www.google.de:80")
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/text/template