# Are golang types inferred at runtime or compile time?

Tags: go

I was wondering if using `:=` and not specifying the variable type reduces performance in Go.

Comment: If you simply want to quell worries about hurting your performance: no, short variable declarations won't hurt your programs performance.  If you want an in depth explanation, hopefully someone more knowledgeable can help you out.

Comment: no, even though you are not explictly setting the type, the compiler will deduce it given the left hand side.

Comment: you can try it for yourself using the parser package (https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) and using it to browse declarations. You will see it does always figure out a type.

Comment: there is a similar question that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024884/does-a-type-assertion-type-switch-have-bad-performance-is-slow-in-go

Comment: [This](https://play.golang.org/p/ppXDw-XJ7E7) does not compile: what does this tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Using `:=` does not impact performance.