# Convert []interface to []string in Golang

Tags: string, go, struct, interface, slice

I'm using the [github.com/fatih/structs](http://github.com/fatih/structs) package to convert values of all fields of a struct into `[]interface{}` with the `toValues()` function. See [here](https://github.com/fatih/structs/blob/master/structs.go#L174). This works fine, but eventually I want to write the values to a csv file by using the csv package. The `csv.Write()` function requires `[]string` as input.

So in short: how can I easily convert the output of `toValues()` into an array of strings?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can't simply convert `[]interface{}` to `[]string` even if all the values are of concrete type `string`, because those 2 types have different memory layout / representation. For details see [Cannot convert []string to []interface {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990338/cannot-convert-string-to-interface).

You have to define how you want values of different types to be represented by `string` values.

The easiest and sensible way would be to iterate over the values, and use [`fmt.Sprint()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint) to obtain a `string` representation of each, e.g.:

```
t := []interface{}{
    "zero",
    1, 2.0, 3.14,
    []int{4, 5},
    struct{ X, Y int }{6, 7},
}
fmt.Println(t)

s := make([]string, len(t))
for i, v := range t {
    s[i] = fmt.Sprint(v)
}
fmt.Println(s)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NP36eHPvHf)):

```
[zero 1 2 3.14 [4 5] {6 7}]
[zero 1 2 3.14 [4 5] {6 7}]
["zero" "1" "2" "3.14" "[4 5]" "{6 7}"]
```

Comment: Thanks; didn't thought about using fmt.Sprint. Working fine now!

Comment: wow, this helped me so much...
but still I hope for a more robust way with assertion

Comment: @AlirezaSoori you can have this with type assertion: just change `fmt.Sprint(v)` with `v.(string)`.

Comment: @icza - This is weird - I've tried using this answer for a similar problem, but I simply can't access the []interface{} when iterating, it returns a "cannot range over foobar (type interface{})" error. If you have time I'd greatly appreciate your input - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70611033/cant-convert-interface-to-string-in-go

Comment: This is convoluted+ugly. Go needs to have cleaner methods for such bulk conversions. 

It becomes nightmare to work with JSON otherwise. :(

Comment: @DanieleTesta Because the question asks how to convert `[]interface{}` to `[]string`. `fmt.Sprintf("%v", inter)` produces a single `string`, not a `[]string`.

Answer (score 0):

you can, just do:

```
    func text(msg ...interface{}) string {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%+v", msg...)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use fmt.Sprintf to convert an interface value to a string. In fact, this technique can be used to get a string representation of any data structure.

Here is the code sample,

```
var Foo interface{} = "Value"

str := fmt.Sprintf("%v", Foo)
```