# How do I json decode interface slice in Go?

Tags: go

I am json.Decode()'ing (forgive the shorthand) a json response from an api into a large struct. Within that struct are a few types that are of type []interface{}. I can't figure out how to extract any data from those special nested structs. I have tried using a case switch type checking solution but came up empty handed still. Can someone share their experience with a similar case or point me in the right direction?

```
m := new(largestruct)
if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&m); err != nil{
return err
}
```

The struct field for interface is:

```
Strings []interface{} `json:"strings"`
```

Comment: Can you provide sample JSON data and explain which types you would like to decode that data into?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027826/convert-interface-to-string-in-golang found this. My problem being the response is always "[ ]" so maybe there isn't anything to get anyway..

Comment: @trophyfish Please post the json response in your question post.

Answer (score 2):

Using the switch case you can fetch the value underlying the interface. The function will run recursively until it gets the original type of the parsed json.

```
func fetchValue(value interface{}) { // pass the interface value from the struct in this function as it will run recursively to get the value.
    switch value.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%v is an string \n ", value.(string))
    case bool:
        fmt.Printf("%v is bool \n ", value.(bool))
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("%v is float64 \n ", value.(float64))
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a slice of interface \n ", value)
        for _, v := range value.([]interface{}) {
            fetchValue(v)
        }
    case map[string]interface{}:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a map \n ", value)
        for _, v := range value.(map[string]interface{}) {
            fetchValue(v)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%v is unknown \n ", value)
    }
}
```

The reason behind the types in switch to be limited is defined in the [golang spec for unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) where it is clearly described what values the json will parse into when unmarshaling using interface{}:

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of
>   these in the interface value:

```
bool, for JSON booleans
float64, for JSON numbers
string, for JSON strings
[]interface{}, for JSON arrays
map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
nil for JSON null
```