# Cannot use word (type interface {}) as type string in assignment: need type assertion

Tags: arrays, go, types, interface, type-assertion

I'm new to Go and what i'm doing for some reason doesn't seem very straight-forward to me.

Here is my code:

```
for _, column := range resp.Values {
  for _, word := range column {

    s := make([]string, 1)
    s[0] = word
    fmt.Print(s, "\n")
  }
}
```

and I get the error:

`Cannot use word (type interface {}) as type string in assignment: need type assertion`

`resp.Values` is an array of arrays, all of which are populated with strings.

`reflect.TypeOf(resp.Values)` returns `[][]interface {}`,

`reflect.TypeOf(resp.Values[0])` (which is `column`) returns `[]interface {}`,

`reflect.TypeOf(resp.Values[0][0])` (which is `word`) returns `string`.

My end goal here is to make each word its own array, so instead of having:

`[[Hello, Stack], [Overflow, Team]]`, I would have:
`[[[Hello], [Stack]], [[Overflow], [Team]]]`

Comment: You need to first type assert that the word is actually a string. One, prone-to-panic, way would be `s[0] = word.(string)`.

Comment: ... more [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) and [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

Comment: Have a look if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71930507/18579038

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prescribed way to ensure that a value has some type is to use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), which has two flavors:

```
s := x.(string) // panics if "x" is not really a string.
s, ok := x.(string) // the "ok" boolean will flag success.
```

Your code should probably do something like this:

```
str, ok := word.(string)
if !ok {
  fmt.Printf("ERROR: not a string -> %#v\n", word)
  continue
}
s[0] = str
```