# Golang graphql iterate over map with submap

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct, graphql

Recently I was trying to an implementation of a Mutation Request using GoLang as a Graphql Server, Basically this is the query that i send: As you can see its an array of object that contains **name** and an **array of strings**

```
mutation{
    CellTest(cells:[{name:"lero",child:["1","2"]},{name:"lero2",child:["12","22"]}]){
            querybody
    }
}
```

In my Go code I have a type object that is gonna set the values sent

```
type Cell struct {
    name  string   `json:"name"`
    child []string `json:"child"`
}
```

and a custom array that is gonna be []Cell

```
type Cells []*Cell
```

However when the request is received by GO I get this:
Note that this is the print of **cellsInterface**

> [map[child:[1 2] name:lero] map[child:[12 22] name:lero2]]

How can i get each value and assign those in my **Array Cells**
something like this:

> Cells[0] = {name="first",child={"1","2"}}
>
> Cells[1] = {name="second",child={"hello","good"}}

this is my current attempt:

```
var resolvedCells Cells
cellsInterface := params.Args["cells"].([]interface{})
cellsByte, err := json.Marshal(cellsInterface)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("marshal the input json", err)
    return resolvedCells, err
}

if err := json.Unmarshal(cellsByte, &resolvedCells); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("unmarshal the input json to Data.Cells", err)
    return resolvedCells, err
}

for cell := range resolvedCells {
    fmt.Println(cellsInterface[cell].([]interface{}))
}
```

However this only split the cells array into 0 and 1.

Comment: The `child` is not a map its a slice of integer values. You can loop through them, it is unclear from the question you have asked what actually you want.

Comment: alright what i actually want is to obtain each value that is sended in the Mutation and saved it in a array of Cell (is the type Cell struct at the end)

Comment: i hope that my comment make it a little more clear @Himanshu

Comment: I edit the question so now it'll be more clear

Comment: Yeah we can do that just print the output of `cellsInterface` and `resolvedCells` in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range through the map values in the result and append those values to Cell slice. If you are getting an object from json. Then you can unmarshall the bytes into Cell.

The result when unmarshalling should be a slice of Cell struct as

```
var resolvedCells []Cell
if err := json.Unmarshal(cellsByte, &resolvedCells); err != nil {
                fmt.Println("unmarshal the input json to Data.Cells", err)
    }
fmt.Println(resolvedCells)
```

Working Code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aRXD9FGn1d4)

Or if you want to use pointers loop over the resolvedCell as

```
type Cells []*Cell

func main() {
    var resolvedCells Cells
    if err := json.Unmarshal(cellsByte, &resolvedCells); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("unmarshal the input json to Data.Cells", err)
        }
    fmt.Println(*resolvedCells[1])
    for _, value := range resolvedCells{
        fmt.Println(value)
        fmt.Printf("%+v",value.Child) // access child struct value of array
    }
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/cHJrNy2XrA_f)

Comment: Now i receive an error:   cannot use value (type interface {}) as type *Cell in append: need type assertion

Comment: @LuisCardozaBird Please check edited code you need type assertion to get the underlying value

Comment: I checked with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289256/cannot-convert-data-type-interface-to-type-string-need-type-assertion but they take in consideration just one type of value (string), in this case is String and an Array :/ @Himanshu

Comment: @LuisCardozaBird Its ok just provide me the output of json bytes `fmt.Println(string(cellsByte))`

Comment: this is:  cells byte output:  [{"child":["sasaa","sasa"],"name":"lero"},{"child":["xzxz","ffafa"],"name":"lero2"}]

Comment: @LuisCardozaBird that's what I needed give me sometime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177878/discussion-between-himanshu-and-luis-cardoza-bird).